# MG tool Style Anim Recording option in Blender

Tags: animation, add-on, filmic-blender

In Maya we have a MG tool plugin (Paid) which has this option called as anim Record. Are there any similar options or add on in Blender which can replicate anim record option.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_f8HWoxoX0s

Eg

1. char is jumping from point B to point B
2. we pose and block the char using master ctrls for its positions.
3. Primary stage i need poses but the master control should not have any keys. rathers translation should be driven by COG or root ctrl.

Comment: Which part of this tutorial shows the function you are looking for? Any timecode? Or just everything in this video?

Comment: Hello, could you describe with words or diagrams what you are looking for should behave like ?

Comment: Let me give it a try..... Eg 1)char is jumping from point B to point B 2) we pose and block the char using master ctrls for its positions. 3) Primary stage i need poses but the master control should not have any keys. rathers translation should be driven by COG or root ctrl..   Hope u have understood my explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of functions in Blender is built in: select the involved bones and go to pose mode > pose menu > animation > bake action.

Explore its preferences to reach the goal you desire.

Comment: Thanks Josh for the reply. Will try to explore it ...